# What are the various 'announcements' or 'notices' for package updates?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, debian

Recently, I came across USN - Ubuntu security notices and DSA - debian security announce and found that these are the mail lists for the security updates of the packages.

Is there any other announce like this?

I came across bugfixes and enhancements as type of update like security update, but was never able to find the mail list for it.

Does one exist for these type of updates?

Answer (score 1):

**No**: Neither apt nor snapd listen for such announcements. Both collect their information about updates (including security updates) using a different and more robust method.

Security announcements are intended for human admins who must track security vulnerabilities and patches.

Apt and snapd will happily tell you all available updates anytime you wish:

```
sudo apt update                // update the package database
apt list --upgradeable         // merely listing does not require sudo

snap refresh --list            // merely listing does not require sudo
```

Comment: so there is no mail list for updates which are not security ones?

Comment: @ArunPrakash - Correct: The answer is 'No'

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a list of recently updated packages, check Launchpad: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+queue?queue_state=3 - replace `bionic` with the codename of the release you're interested in (`trusty`, `xenial`, etc.). Each package link shows the change details, and has a `Changes` field. For example, [`gnocchi`](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/400217434/gnocchi_4.2.5-0ubuntu1_amd64.changes):

```
Changes:
 gnocchi (4.2.5-0ubuntu1) bionic; urgency=medium
 .
   * New stable point release for OpenStack Queens (LP: #1806043).
```